# Python 3 - Separate integer list with line breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x

Really simple issue - I'm kicking myself for not being able to do this right now.

```
import random

randomlist = random.sample(range(4410000000000, 4499999999999), 5000000)
print(randomlist)
```

Simple random number generator. I'd like to separate the output, replace the commas with line breaks; so that instead of this:

```
[4469530093951, 4487965258866, 4488296120976, ...]
```

I have this:

```
4469530093951
4487965258866
4488296120976
...
```

I've been trying to use ("\n") line breaks, but that doesn't work with integers apparently - so what's the alternative? Thanks, my apologies for the lack of basic Python knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using separate `print` statements:

```py
for num in randomlist: print(num)
```

This will give your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in randomlist]))
```

Answer (score 0):

import random

randomlist = random.sample(range(4410000000000, 4499999999999), 5000000)
print(randomlist)

for item in randomlist:
print(item)